# XSL transform in Oracle using XMLTYPE.TRANSFORM returns a fragment, document required

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, xmltype

This should be an easy one...

In Oracle I am using XMLTYPE.TRANSFORM(myxml, myxsl) to perform a transformation.

The XMLTYPE returned is a fragment (i.e. there is no XML document declaration). I require the output to be a document (i.e. with the `<?XML version="1.0" ?>` declaration).

My trasform works fine using standalone tools.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by prepending the declaration string to the CLOB output like so : `return ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' || xmltype.GETCLOBVAL(L_RESULT));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use sys_xmlgen:

`select sys_xmlgen(xmlforest(a.value, a.value2)) from

(select 'value' value, 2 value2 from dual) a`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it inserts the resulting document in an enclosing `<ROW>` element which invalidates it according to the schema it needs to be matched to. It seems that XMLTYPE.TRANSFORM reasonably assumes that the resulting document may not be well formed, so returns just a fragment. I want to keep all of my XML to XML formatting in the stylesheet only, let it do the work.